# Migration issues in socket.io 2.x to 4.x in node js

Tags: node.js, socket.io-1.0, socket.io-redis, socket.io-client

`

```
type here
```

migration issues in socket.io , i was using socket.io 2.x version and socket.io-client 2.x and socket.io-redis 5.x but now I'm migrated to socket.io 4.x , socket.io-client 4.x and socket.io-redis 6.x so when i do this
`self.io.adapter(new RedisAdapter( { pubClient : self.redis.pub, subClient : self.redis.sub }));`"

i got this error
`!!SETREDISADAPTER ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'encoder') parky-rest-api-dev-0  |     at new Adapter (/home/nelson/Desktop/parkfex/node_modules/socket.io-redis/node_modules/socket.io-adapter/dist/index.js:16:35)`

I checked the notes but I still struggle understanding them `